# JPA Discriminator Value

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have a problem with JPA and Discriminator Value.
value=0 should be mapped as a `user` and value=1 should be mapped as a `admin` but I only get the users

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_USERS")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="usergroup", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public abstract class UserModel implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="T_USERS_PK")
private int id;
@Column(name="username")
private String username;
@Column(name="password")
private String password;
@Column(name="firstname")
private String firstname;
@Column(name="lastname")
private String lastname;
@Column(name="usergroup")
private String usergroup;
```

-

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("0")
public class User extends UserModel {
```

-

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class Admin extends UserModel {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your usergroup is string and you set discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER

```
@Column(name="usergroup")
private String usergroup;
```

Change userGroup type to integer and if it is string in your database (type of userGroup field in table) then **remove** discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="usergroup")
```

because defalut of discriminatorType is string.

Comment: I've changed it to Integer and tested it even with int but same problem.. in the database the type of the field is int

Comment: you mean you changed also the type of field in database? I see also in your code that you mapp zero(0) to user and one (1) to Admin ?is it what you want ?

Comment: if you changed to integer you should also change @DiscriminatorValue("0") to @DiscriminatorValue(0) and "1" to 1 for Admin..

Comment: user(0) admin(1) correct... i've founded the problem it was in the query   return em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM UserModel c", UserModel.class).getResultList(); instead of UserModel I had User